# Conver SVG Animate (points) into CSS

Tags: javascript, svg

I use a SVG animations and they work well. But my Chome (Version 51.0.2704.103 m) tells that:

```
SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
```

So that can you please help me to convert the code into CSS animation to satisfy the browser:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">
  <polygon fill="#FFD41D" points="97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 67.2,60.9">
    <animate id="animation-to-check" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="110,58.2 147.3,0 192.1,29 141.7,105.1 118.7,139.8 88.8,185.1 46.1,156.5 0,125 23.5,86.6 71.1,116.7"/>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

This is how I launch the code:

`document.getElementById("animation-to-check").beginElement();`

[JS fiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/t7tn8fnh/)

Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the polyfill e.g.: https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation/blob/master/test/testcases/append-target.html

Comment: I've no experience with the library, I use/develop Firefox which has all this natively. When Chrome dropped native support they announced that this library was developed as the replacement for lack of native support.

Comment: @Tomas. It is a polyfill library. Which should mean that all you need to do is include it on your page, or in your SVG.  It will take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved rather simply with the help of the [SVG-Morpheus library](http://alexk111.github.io/SVG-Morpheus/). The snippet below shows how it can be used to animate a morphing transition from one SVG polygon to another. If you would like to edit the snippet yourself, I've also made a [codepen sandbox for it](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKrgzx).

```js
const icons = new SVGMorpheus('#icons');
icons.to('check', {
  duration: 500,
  easing: 'quad-in-out',
  rotation: 'none'
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
}
g {
  fill: #FFD41D;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SVG-Morpheus/0.3.2/svg-morpheus.js"></script>
  <svg id="icons" viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">
    <g id="check">
      <polygon points="110,58.2 147.3,0 192.1,29 141.7,105.1 118.7,139.8 88.8,185.1 46.1,156.5 0,125 23.5,86.6 71.1,116.7"/>
    </g>
    <g id="star">
      <polygon points="97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 67.2,60.9"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It can help somebody but i still need a pure solution without 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Are you wanting to avoid using javascript all together and achieve the desired effect only using CSS?

Comment: I would like to avoid foreign libraries and just launch CSS transformations by JS as same as SMIL does

Comment: Unfortunately, [as mentioned in this article/tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/#animating-svg-paths), this is not yet possible without the use of JavaScript entirely or the `<animate/>` tag. It would appear that, if you're not using some sort of library like [SVG-Morpheus](http://alexk111.github.io/SVG-Morpheus/) or [Snap.SVG](http://snapsvg.io/), you will either have to write your own JavaScript animation from the ground up or continue using the depreciated `<animate/>` tag.